# Javascript : DataTables.net with lazy loading replacing paging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

how i can use lazy loading concept in datatables.net and disable paging
while rows will increase automatically

Comment: Please add some part of your source code, so we can see what exactly you are trying to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [Scroller](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension, it's a virtual rendering plug-in for DataTables which allows large datasets to be drawn on screen very quickly.

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ordering: false,
    searching: false,
    ajax: '/script.php',
    dom: "rtiS",
    scrollY: 200,
    scroller: {
        loadingIndicator: true
    }
} );
```

Please note that in server-side processing mode response should have certain format, see [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more information.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9Ls13q5/) for code and demonstration.